# No output for regular expression with grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to extract part of a string using grep with a regular expression. I already tested the regex using [regexr](https://regexr.com) and it's working. I'm on macOS.

This is my code:

`echo -e '"HI":"Hola!"' | grep -o '(?=[^\"]).+?(?=":")'`

If I try to use the `-P` option it shows the usage description for grep:

```
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
        [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
        [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
        [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

I want to get `HI` as the output. Do I need to pipe the `grep` output or am I missing something else?

Thanks

Comment: You did not test the regex with the compatible regex tester. POSIX BRE regex does not support lookarounds. Did you mean to use `echo -e '"HI:"Hola!""' | grep -Po '(?<=").+?(?=:")'`?

Comment: You're right, I use [regexr](https://regexr.com) to test. The `-P` option doesn't work, I'm on macOS. I'm gonna update the problem description.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the `-P` option. I had to install grep with `brew`. Theres was an issue with the `grep` version on macOS. The resulting code is this: ```echo -e '"HI":"Hola!"' | ggrep -Po '(?=[^\"]).+?(?=":")'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU-grep :

```
$ echo '"HI:"Hola!""' | grep -oP '\w+(?=:)'
HI
```

or with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ echo '"HI:"Hola!""' | perl -lne 'print $& if /\w+(?=:)/'
HI
```

[look around explained](https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444)

Comment: I updated the problem description. If I try to use the `-P` option it shows the usage description for grep.

Comment: What is the message ? Try man `grep` to know if the switch is implemented. Wich distro ? Which grep ? Need GNU grep

Comment: Added perl solution

Comment: Couldn't use the `-P` because of my version of `grep`. I had to install grep using homebrew. The resulting code is this: ```echo -e '"HI":"Hola!"' | ggrep -Po '(?=[^\"]).+?(?=":")'```. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a perl-compatible version of `grep` , try `sed` -

```
$: echo -e '"HI:"Hola!""' | sed -En '/".*?:"/ { s/.*"(.*?):".*/\1/; p; }'
HI
```

This grabs the first occurance of everything between `"` and `:"`. Please clarify your parameters if that's not right.

Also, you could just use `perl`. :)

Comment: I didn't have a Perl compatible version. I had to install it via homebrew and use it as `ggrep`. Thanks

Comment: The `sed` would probably have been easier, lol ;)